# R - Connecting R and java using Rserve

Tags: java, r, memory, memory-management, rserve

I have build an application connecting R and java using the Rserve package. 
In that, i am getting the error as "evaluation successful but object is too big to transport". i have tried increasing the send buffer size value in Rconnection class also. but that doesn't seem to work.
The object size which is being transported is 4 MB

here is the code from the R connection file

public void setSendBufferSize(long sbs) throws RserveException {

```
    if (!connected || rt == null) {
        throw new RserveException(this, "Not connected");
    }
    try {
        RPacket rp = rt.request(RTalk.CMD_setBufferSize, (int) sbs);
        System.out.println("rp is send buffer "+rp);
        if (rp != null && rp.isOk()) {
            System.out.println("in if " + rp);
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LogOut.log.error("Exception caught" + e);
    }

    //throw new RserveException(this,"setSendBufferSize failed",rp);        
}
```

The full java class is available here :[Rconnection.java](https://github.com/s-u/REngine/blob/master/Rserve/RConnection.java)

Comment: It might help others if you add some code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of RServe, you can use JRI, that is shipped with rJava package.

In my opinion JRI is better than RServe, because instead of creating a separate process it uses native calls to integrate Java and R.

With JRI you don't have to worry about ports, connections, watchdogs, etc... The calls to R are done using an operating system library (libjri).

The methods are pretty similar to RServe, and you can still use REXP objects.

Here is an example:

```
public void testMeanFunction() {

    // just making sure we have the right version of everything
    if (!Rengine.versionCheck()) {
        System.err.println("** Version mismatch - Java files don't match library version.");
        fail(String.format("Invalid versions. Rengine must have the same version of native library. Rengine version: %d. RNI library version: %d", Rengine.getVersion(), Rengine.rniGetVersion()));
    }

    // Enables debug traces
    Rengine.DEBUG = 1;

    System.out.println("Creating Rengine (with arguments)");
    // 1) we pass the arguments from the command line
    // 2) we won't use the main loop at first, we'll start it later
    // (that's the "false" as second argument)
    // 3) no callback class will be used
    engine = REngine.engineForClass("org.rosuda.REngine.JRI.JRIEngine", new String[] { "--no-save" }, null, false);
    System.out.println("Rengine created...");

    engine.parseAndEval("rVector=c(1,2,3,4,5)");
    REXP result = engine.parseAndEval("meanVal=mean(rVector)");
    // generic vectors are RVector to accomodate names
    assertThat(result.asDouble()).isEqualTo(3.0);
}
```

I have a demo project that exposes a REST API and calls R functions using this package.

Take a look at: https://github.com/jfcorugedo/RJavaServer

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/200235)

Comment: ok, you're right. I'm improving my answer adding a basic example an the reason I think JRI is better than RServe

Comment: If you expose REST API from JRI R calls, you will get monothread web services. Use Rserve for scalable services.

Comment: Yes, you’re right. In fact I ended up coding both approaches and use one or the other depending on several factors. If you’re interested take a look at my repository